# What are all the certificates mandatory to be provide while setting TLSVerifyClient option to demand

Tags: ssl-certificate, ldap, openldap, slapd, pam-ldap

In my case, I had set **TLSVerifyClient** to ***demand***. I couldn't be able to establish a connection While providing **TLSCACertificateFile** ***alone***.

While setting the TLSVerifyClient option demand is it mandatory to provide the following option or  TLSCACertificateFile is enough?

TLSCACertificateFile

TLSCertificateKeyFile

TLSCertificateFile

Regards,

Ram

Answer (score 0):

By setting [`TLSVerifyClient`](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin23/tls.html) to anything different than `never` you allow ***mutual TLS.***

As implied already in the name: mutual SSL/TLS requires that ***both client and server authenticate themselves with certificates***.

The mechanism of TLS client authentication (only) sends the client certificate over TLS,  as part of the authentication handshake.

On the server that requires and means you can't do without:

- a server certificate `TLSCertificateFile`
- the associated private key `TLSCertificateKeyFile` for the server certificate
- additionally the certificate authority that is trusted to issue client certificates is needed. `TLSCACertificateFile <filename>` OR  `TLSCACertificatePath <path>`

As a nice curiosity: the certificate authority that is trusted to issue client certificates does not have to be same one that issues the server certificate. Typically it is not. Your server certificate for example is issued by Let’sEncrypt and you would use an internal CA for client certificates.

---

On the client you first need to trust the CA certificate (chain) used to issue the server certificate. Often that doesn’t need to be configured explicitly as the system defaults for the client often already have the correct trusts built in. That is governed by the [client settings](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin23/tls.html):  `TLS_CACERT` and/or `TLS_CACERTDIR`.

Then for the client to identify itself with mutual TLS it needs its own certificate and associated private key. Set with `TLS_CERT` respectively `TLS_KEY` directives.

Comment: Hi HBruijn, Sorry for the inconvenience. I thought user tag will define those items. I facing problems in the LDAP server and LDAP client.

Comment: My apologies but for me tags are no substitute for information that belongs in the question itself.